# Silverlight ObservableCollection cannot get data from EntityQuery

Tags: silverlight, observablecollection

I am trying to get data that are returned from an EntityQuery

```
public EntityQuery<Product> GetProductsQuery()
```

and I am using an ObservableCollection to store them

```
var query = ctx.GetProductsQuery();
        ctx.Load(query, op =>
                             {
                                 var data = op.Entities;
                                 ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(op.Entities);

                                 return;
                             }, null);
```

but after this code, the ProductList is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of links hope they shed more light on your issue. They describe how to load data from RIA serives into ObservableCollections

[Loading WCF RIA Services Query results to an ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163674/loading-wcf-ria-services-query-results-to-an-observablecollection)

[Loading Data from RIA Services](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-loading-data-from-ria-services.html)